# Display MySQL table attributes via a foreign key relationship using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have two tables `job` which contains an attribute called `employer_id_job` that links it to the `employer` table. I am able to display the contents of `job` in a table using PHP by using the following code

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM job";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);

    $count = 0;
    while ($count < $num)
    {
        $title = mysql_result ($result, $count, "Title");
        $date_posted = mysql_result ($result, $count, "Date_posted");
        $application_deadline = mysql_result ($result, $count, "Application_deadline");
        $description = mysql_result ($result, $count, "Description");
        $years_of_experience = mysql_result ($result, $count, "Years_of_experience");
        $education_level = mysql_result ($result, $count, "Education_level_required");
        $contract = mysql_result ($result, $count, "Contract_type");
        $company = mysql_result ($result, $count, "Company_name");
?>

        <tr>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $count + 1; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $title; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $company; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $description; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $date_posted; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $application_deadline; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $education_level; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $years_of_experience; ?></font></td>
        <td><font face = "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $contract; ?></font></td>
<?
        $count ++;
    }
?>
```

My method here breaks down when trying to assign a value to the `$company` variable, which is held in the `employer` table. It was my assumption that simply using the same notation as for the rest of my variables would cause the script to follow the foreign key to the `employer` table and grab the attributes there, but it hasn't done that.

How should I go about accessing the contents of a table related via a foreign key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from job as j, company as c where j.company == c.company
```

I'm not sure what then name of your fields are so I made my best guess.  This allows you to access both fields.